# Save and reload screen in opengl

Tags: opengl, load, save

I have written a program like ms paint with glut/opengl and i want to save current screen and reload after some drawing.
How to save current display screen into a variable and reload when needed?

Answer (score 0):

You'll likely want to store it in a Framebuffer Object, and swap those out at will.
This depends strongly on your use-case scenario, though.

http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer_Object

Comment: T do this which library should i use.

Comment: I'd recommend handling the objects manually with OpenGL calls.  It might actually be better to use a [Pixel Buffer Object](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Pixel_Buffer_Object), but to be honest, we'd need more information on the language, and how you're currently handling things.
There are some memory tracking implications which may require swapping to RAM when necessary, but it would probably be in your best interest to fully utilize the GPU hardware available.  If you'd like to stay mostly off of the graphics hardware, it's just a matter of handling different pixel arrays.